# notifyDataSetChanged() from different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifydatasetchanged

I currently have 3 fragments(tabs) and is currently using a viewpager. I have 1 listview for each fragment, and i want to notify the other when something happens, after clicking the view. I tried using the notifyDataSetChanged() on setOnPageChangeListener() on the mainactivity. Problem is, i can see the data being inserted when i change tabs. Since the change happens after changing tabs.

Comment: Since you're using a view pager,it has an option to select how many fragments need to be loaded on either side of the current fragment,say 1.So 1 fragment will be loaded on either side of the current one,so if you tried to refer to any fragment other than these,odds are either nothing will happen or it will crash and tell you no such view or adapter exists,this is not an answer but something to look out for when you do get it,i am in need of the same thing too.

Comment: Thanks for the note. It's really annoying seeing the data being populate after changing tabs. XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using broadcast receivers to notify data set change.

**In your receiving fragment**

```
public static final string RADIO_DATASET_CHANGED = "com.yourapp.app.RADIO_DATASET_CHANGED";

private Radio radio;
```

In the onCreate method :

```
radio = new Radio();
```

The radio class inside the receiving fragment :

```
private class Radio extends BroadcastReceiver{
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(RADIO_DATASET_CHANGED)){
                    //Notify dataset changed here
                }
        }
```

In the receiving fragment on resume method :

```
@Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();                    
                //using intent filter just in case you would like to listen for more transmissions
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                filter.addAction(RADIO_DATASET_CHANGED);                    
                getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(radio, filter);
        }
```

Make sure we unregister receiver in the onDestroy method

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(radio);
    }catch (Exception e){
        //Cannot unregister receiver
    }

}
```

**Fragment transmitting dataset changed**

Then from the fragment which is notifying datasetchange just do :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ReceivingFragment.RADIO_DATASET_CHANGED);
getActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Well, IT FREAKING WORKED! :D i'm going nuts right now if you can just see me. Thank you so much. :D I just noticed the the notifydatasetchanged() was been causing my tab swipe to slow down. It didn't work when i tried the notifydatasetchaned, instead i called my list again. it worked. and its smoother than before. :)

Comment: Just curious? how does the unregisteredReceiver() work? I can't seem to call it?

Comment: I see sry..its getActivity().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(radio);

Comment: @RenzRazon what did you mean by call your list again?Did you regenerate the data?

Comment: @JudeFernandes yup, not sure if that was a good move though. I'm still starting in android, need to learn more. xD

Comment: @RenzRazon i used a recycler view for all my tabs and used a default animator so whenever i add a tab i use the notify item inserted which also gives a sweet little animation,you should use the view holder patter for list view to increase performance.

Comment: @JudeFernandes  i wish i knew these stuff ealier, im still using eclipse though, i plan on changing to studio after this project. :) eclipse has a lot of bugs and problems. Looking forward to using those views you suggested.

Comment: dont think twice and change to android studio :)

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity .Try with this code. It may help.

```
 @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position ==0 )
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (position == 1)
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
if (position == 2)
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I think that's precicely what @Renz is doing right now

Comment: That is where i putted it. on the onpageslected of the setonpagechangelistener.